# How do I scrape the 'next' page in the Scrapy Tutorial?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm doing the [scrapy tutorial](https://python.gotrained.com/scrapy-tutorial-web-scraping-craigslist/#Craigslist_Scrapy_Spider_2_One_Page) and am on the 'Craigslist Scrapy Spider #3 – Multiple Pages' section but am unable to get more than one page after following the instructions given. The only difference between what I did and what the tutorial showed was I used 'all jobs' rather than only engineering jobs (since there was only one page of engineering jobs). Below is the code I have

```
import scrapy

from scrapy import Request

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs-new'
    allowed_domains = ['craigslist.org']
    start_urls = ['https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/jjj']

def parse(self, response):
    

    jobs = response.xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]')
    for job in jobs:
        title = job.xpath('a/text()').extract_first()
        address = job.xpath('span[@class="result-meta"]/span[@class="result-hood"]/text()').extract_first("")[2:-1]
        relative_url = job.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)

        yield{'URL':absolute_url, 'Title':title, 'Address':address}
    

    relative_next_url = response.xpat('//a[@class="button next"]/@href').extract_first()
    absolute_next_url = response.urljoin(relative_next_url)

    yield request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

I ran this in a terminal using

```
scrapy crawl jobs-new -o jobs-new.csv
```

but there was only the first page of results within the `.csv` file.

What do I need to do to get more than one page? Is the tutorial incorrect or did I understand it incorrectly?

Comment: Please put your code as text not as image.

Comment: You have a type  "response.xpat" , Its xpath and last line will yield Request not yield request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edit your code and found it ok.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs-new'
    allowed_domains = ['craigslist.org']
    start_urls = ['https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/jjj']

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]')
        for job in jobs:
            title = job.xpath('a/text()').extract_first()
            address = job.xpath('span[@class="result-meta"]/span[@class="result-hood"]/text()').extract_first("")[2:-1]
            relative_url = job.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)

            yield {'URL': absolute_url, 'Title': title, 'Address': address}

        relative_next_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="button next"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_url = response.urljoin(relative_next_url)

        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Here is some output

```
{'URL': 'https://newyork.craigslist.org/brk/trp/d/brooklyn-overnight-parking-attendant/7166876233.html', 'Title': 'Overnight Parking Attendant', 'Address': 'Brooklyn, NY'}
```

{'URL': 'https://newyork.craigslist.org/wch/fbh/d/yonkers-experience-grill-man/7166875818.html', 'Title': 'Experience grill man', 'Address': 'Yonkers'}